Installing program on CentOs cluster for a non-root user
I am a beginner and want to install Material Studio 2023 in CentOs (version 7) cluster. I would appreciate any comments on my attempts which comes as follows:
My tries:
I used ssh to connect to the cluster and did as follows:

I unzipped the file with tar -xvzf

I chose allowed directory for installation.

I chose a directory for The BIOVIA License Pack. Then I get this message:
this directory does not appear to contain a supported License Pack installation. Would you like to install it to that location? [Y/n]


In this case, I selected "yes".

For the Gateway service, I do not exactly know What purpose is this option used for? So, I used "no" for the following message:
Do you want to start the Gateway service after installation? If you want to configure security settings before starting or if you do not want to run the service, enter n (Y/n)

About the Apache, since I do not know it, I used "no" again!
Do you expect to require Apache?

Finally, I failed to instll with this error:


Running LicensePack installation...
/share/Materials Studio-2023-v23x64/MaterialsStudio2023/LicensePack/lp_setup: line 112: /share/Materials: No such file or directory
WARNING: You have either chosen to cancel your installation, or an error has occurred.
Please Verify your usage is correct:
Usage: lp_setup [-silent] [-console] [-P licensepack.installLocation=] [-V PRODUCT_LP_FILE=] [Port@HostName] [ -C ]
   -silent - installs the product in silent mode.
   -console - installs the product in console mode.
   -P licensepack.installLocation - allows the user to specify the location to install License Pack.
   -V PRODUCT_LP_FILE - write License Pack Install directory to file.
    Port@HostName - specify the port@hostname of the License Pack server.
   -C - to run License Pack Compatibility Mode on silent.

If usage is correct please refer to FAQ section of the LicensePack documentation or contact BIOVIA Support.
The LicensePack documentation index is called LicensePack.html and is located on the CD.
Return Code: 127
LicensePack installation failed

This looks like an issue with the installer not being able to handle spaces in the path component Materials Studio-2023-v23x64
